# How to show a tooltip using the mouse right click on a combo box?

Tags: c#, combobox, tooltip

I want that on rihgt mouse click, something happend like this:

```
  private void ComboBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            string name = "גובה: " + (SelectedItem as student).Hight.ToString() + "   דרגת פטפוט:" + (SelectedItem as student).Level_garrulity.ToString();
            this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, name);
        }
    }
```

isn't working, but if I change  it to left click it's ok.
what can be the problem?

Comment: Change to `this.ComboBox1.MouseUp += this.ComboBox1_MouseClick;`

Comment: it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The mouse right click of a combo box is dedicated for the contextual menu.

If there is no contextual menu associated to the combo box, the standard windows system menu is showned.

To do what you want as you want you need to shunt that with a dummy menu:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public FormTest()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ComboBox1.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
  ComboBox1.ContextMenuStrip.Opening += ComboBox1_RightMouseClick;
}

private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(new student() { Name = "name 1", Hight = 10, Level_garrulity = 1 });
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(new student() { Name = "name 2", Hight = 20, Level_garrulity = 2 });
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(new student() { Name = "name 3", Hight = 30, Level_garrulity = 3 });
}

private void ComboBox1_RightMouseClick(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  var item = ComboBox1.SelectedItem as student;
  if (item == null ) return;
  string name = "גובה: " + item.Hight.ToString()
              + "   דרגת פטפוט:" + item.Level_garrulity.ToString();
  toolTip1.SetToolTip(ComboBox1, name);
}
```

But there is some problems and I found that the result is a bad UX.

Thus instead, I recommend to you to use the mouse hover event, hence if an item is selected, the tooltip is shown, but it needs the combo box to be a drop down list to works perfectly else several mouse moves are needed, but the result can be better than the right click, if it matches your goal:

```
public FormTest()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
}

private void ComboBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var item = ComboBox1.SelectedItem as student;
  if ( item == null ) return;
  string name = "גובה: " + item.Hight.ToString()
              + "   דרגת פטפוט:" + item.Level_garrulity.ToString();
  toolTip1.SetToolTip(ComboBox1, name);
}
```

Hence, the tooltip is always up to date, unlike the version with the right click of the mouse.

[image]